# Multiple "if" variables in if else statement

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, if-statement

I'm new to Objective-C. How do I change this code to make it "username AND password" rather than "OR password"?

```
if ([name isEqualToString:@"haseo98"] || [pass isEqualToString:@"passwordtest"]){
    [_loginwindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#Boolean_Logical_Operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OR --> ||

AND --> &&

```
if ([name isEqualToString:@"haseo98"] && [pass isEqualToString:@"passwordtest"]){
    [_loginwindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use &&. Just like in plain C.